# ClearCase single stream UCM project: When are changes visible in a snapshot view?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Consider a single stream UCM project in ClearCase.
Each developer works in her own snapshot view on the integration stream of the project.

According to the ClearCase documentation when a developer completes an activity, the changes made by the activity become visible to the rest of the developers.

When developer `A` completes an activity `P`, are the changes of `P` immediately visible to developer `B` and `C`?
Or do `B` and `C` have to refresh their snapshot view in order to actually see the changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a snapshot view (UCM or not), you always have to "[`cleartool update`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm)" your view in order to see the changes committed by your colleagues.

Note: the notion of "completing an activity" might suggest that you are actually using ClearCase with ClearQuest (which will check-in all checked out files associated with an activity, when the related ClearQuest work item is "completed").

This is valid for single-stream UCM projects as well as multi-streams: every time you have several *snapshot* views on a single stream, you need an update to see your colleagues' commits.